# Why doesn't the SageMath function find_local_maximum work for me in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spyder, nameerror, sage

I'm attempting to use the SageMath code written in the post [How to find the approximate basic period or GCD of a list of numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914288/how-to-find-the-approximate-basic-period-or-gcd-of-a-list-of-numbers). This code works in CoCalc, but I can't get it to run in Python in my IDE. I've imported numpy and sagemath, and referred to each as needed to define the math functions, but I can't get the find_local_maximum function to work. See below.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import sagemath as sm

def mean_x(factor, values):
    return sum([np.cos(2*np.pi*v/factor) for v in values])/len(values)

def mean_y(factor, values):
    return sum([np.sin(2*np.pi*v/factor) for v in values])/len(values)

def calculatePeriodAppeal(factor, values):
    mx = mean_x(factor, values)
    my = mean_y(factor, values)
    appeal = np.sqrt(mx**2+my**2)
    return appeal

def calculateBestLinear(factor, values):
    mx = mean_x(factor, values).n()
    my = mean_y(factor, values).n()
    y0 = factor*np.atan2(my,mx)/(2*np.pi).n()
    err = 1-np.sqrt(mx**2+my**2).n()
    return [factor*x + y0, err]

def calculateGCDAppeal(factor, values):
    mx = mean_x(factor, values)
    my = mean_y(factor, values)
    appeal = 1 - np.sqrt((mx-1)**2+my**2)/2
    return appeal

testSeq = [552,827,275,809,534] 
gcd = calculateGCDAppeal(x, testSeq)
agcd = sm.find_local_maximum(gcd,20,30)
print(agcd)
np.plot(gcd,(x, 20,30))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-163-fecb5397afab>", line 31, in <module>
    agcd = sm.find_local_maximum(gcd,20,30)

AttributeError: module 'sagemath' has no attribute 'find_local_maximum'
```

Comment: Note: also asked (and answered) as
[Ask Sage question 53203: Why doesn't the SageMath function find_local_maximum work for me in Python?](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/53203)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you ran `pip install sagemath` which installs
the "sagemath" package from PyPI:

- [PyPI: sagemath](https://pypi.org/project/sagemath/)

That is a dummy package and by doing that you did not install SageMath.

Making the Sage library pip-installable is work in progress, tracked at

- [Sage Trac ticket 21507: Meta-ticket: Make sagelib a pip-installable Python source package, listed on PyPI](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/21507)

Currently, accessing SageMath functionality requires actually
installing SageMath, not the dummy "sagemath" package from PyPI.

If the goal is to use it alongside Spyder, see the answer to

- [Ask Sage question 53244: How do I start using SageMath in Spyder on macOS?](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/53244)

where the advice is to follow the simplest route and
install both Sage and Spyder via Conda.